# Is possible to set firebase custom properties analytics as array?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I'm planning to use Firebase Analytics for my Apps. According to Firebase Docs is possible to set custom user properties docs here [Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/properties) and [IOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/ios/properties). Latter one can use the properties to create audiences in Firebase Analytics Dashboard as described here [Analytics DashBoard](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317509?hl=en)

I want to use a user custom property as an Array.

For example:

Setting user property to **TagsUserLikes**=["**hashtagBlue**","**hashtagRed**","**hashtagGreen**"] so latter one I'll be able to track an audience of all the users that follow a particular tag, meaning users that contain the tag in the array.

So latter in the Analytics dashboard a audience defined solely as TagsUserLikes="**hastagBlue**" will match all users that contain this tag ["**hashtagBlue**","**hashtagRed**","**hashtagGreen**"] and ["**hashtagBlue**","**hashtagDogs**"],?

Is this supported in the Google Analytics Dashboard (create audience)? 
Is this supported in the Google Big Query?

If Yes How can I achieve this?

tks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although you could theoretically concatenate a list of tags in one User Property value (and use it for audience creation), the limit on the length of User Property values (36 characters) might make this approach impractical for you.

Alternatively, you can log an event such as "tag_followed" with a parameter "tag_name=" and then you can create an audience of users who log tag_followed with a particular tag_name value.

Comment: Tks. I wasn't aware of Property 36 characters constrain